# How to tell JohnTheRipper to solve a password using multiple hashes?

Tags: john-the-ripper

I have 6 archive files in 7zip format. They have the same password. I use the perl script `7z2john` to generate a hash for each of the archives.

I try to combine the hashes into a hashes file, then pass it to `john`. Is it possible to tell `john` the hashes representing the same password?

```
$ ./JohnTheRipper/run/john combined.hashes --session=COMBINED
Warning: detected hash type "7z", but the string is also recognized as "7z-opencl"
Use the "--format=7z-opencl" option to force loading these as that type instead
Using default input encoding: UTF-8
Loaded 6 password hashes with 6 different salts (7z, 7-Zip [SHA256 256/256 AVX2 8x AES])
Cost 1 (iteration count) is 524288 for all loaded hashes
Loaded hashes with cost 2 (padding size) varying from 0 to 8
Loaded hashes with cost 3 (compression type) varying from 0 to 1
Will run 8 OpenMP threads
Press 'q' or Ctrl-C to abort, almost any other key for status
```

I hope the password could be solved easier than just 1 hash (or it's just my imagination?).

I tried to solve the password using 1 hash, but `john` spent more than 120 days to crack, still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to combine multiple hashes in order to speed up a brute-force attack. In your case the hashes seem to use the same algorithm, which means it doesn't matter which hash you try to crack.

Comment: that's sad. 1 more question: is the Stage 3 of John's default mechanism, Incremental mode, equal to brute-force attack? Seems it's more like trying passwords in random order, instead of trying password in sequence.

Comment: On the other hand, I'm using `rarcrack` to brute force password in sequence (an abvious slow inefficient way).